# How do I select previous date from my temp #date table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

Hi have one `temp #Dates table` which is populated by using following condition.

```
IF @Period = 'Monthly'
    BEGIN
        INSERT #Dates
        SELECT MAX(DATE) WeekDays FROM TABLENAV  WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED) 
        GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATE)
        ORDER BY MAX(DATE) DESC
    END
```

now data is in #Dates temp table is

```
DATE
2013-04-22 00:00:00.000
2013-03-29 00:00:00.000
2013-02-28 00:00:00.000
2013-01-31 00:00:00.000
2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
2012-11-30 00:00:00.000
```

I want to get the `Previous_Date` when I'm passing any `Todays_Date`

I tried like following

```
DECLARE @Todays_Date datetime = '2013-04-22'
    select date from #Dates where MONTH(DATE) = MONTH(@Todays_Date)-1  AND YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(@Todays_Date)
```

`giving ans : 2013-03-29`

But when Year changes , I'm getting nothing as ans

For example
If `@Todays_Date = '2012-01-31'` it should return me `2012-12-31` but giving nothing.

Help me to modify my `select statement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max([Date]) FROM #Date WHERE [Date] <@Todays_Date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot easy fix I didn't get it because of procedure complexity :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below query to get the previous date,

```
SELECT top 1 Date FROM #Date WHERE Date <@Todays_Date order by date desc
```